# add multiple form button scroll bars at once from vba

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I need the below macro to reference another sub change event to loop reference to the row number of the scroll bar, i and then adjust the cell `Bi` . So far I can only get 100 scroll bars to reference only B2

```
Sub Tester88()
    Dim ScrollBar As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = 99 'Modify as needed this will be the last possible row to add a button

    For i = 2 To lastRow Step 4
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 18)  'Column 3, row i

        '## Create the button object and assign a variable to represent it
        Set ScrollBar = ActiveSheet.ScrollBars.Add(1, 1, 1, 1)

        '## use the btn variable to manipulate the button:
        With ScrollBar
            .Top = rng.Top
            .Left = rng.Left
            .width = rng.width
            .height = rng.RowHeight
            .Value = 1
            .Min = 1
            .Max = 100
            .SmallChange = 1
            .LargeChange = 10
            .LinkedCell = "$B$2"
            .Display3DShading = True

        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just put the row in .LinkedCell instead of having it hardcoded. You've set it to a range of 1-100; keep in mind if you are using LinkedCell you are *directly* controlling the value of the cell, so if you are controlling data that has an existing set of values you need to either set the range (and the value) to the existing value of the cell, or have it as a cell that just shows the scroll bar value and use a formula referencing that cell for the final result you want.+

Comment: o I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Please ask questions related to the button issue in that question, not this one. Since this solution uses linked cells rather than an event handler it is not relevant. Are you sure that is the source of the delay? If you hardcode everything to row 7 or whatever is it faster?

Comment: Also what do you mean you have no idea to how do that? It's simple string manipulation, `"$B$" + CStr(i)` - do you have any programming experience at all?

Comment: Thanks I will try that - I did try "Bi" and "B & i"

Comment: Whatever you do for something like this it needs to be outside the quotes or it will just be part of the string.

Comment: keep in mind if you are using LinkedCell you are directly controlling the value of the cell, so if you are controlling data that has an existing set of values  - yeah it will change an existing cell value. What you said after this flew over me

Comment: The value of the cell is going to be exactly the value of the scrollbar (from 1 to 100, 50 if the scrollbar is in the middle), rather than just adding one to its original value whenever you increase the scrollbar... so you need to make sure that the value of the scrollbar is actually in the range you want B2 to be in.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this task, so:

```
Sub Tester88()
    Dim ScrollBar As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = 99 'Modify as needed this will be the last possible row to add a button

    For i = 2 To lastRow Step 4
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 13)  'Column 3, row i

        '## Create the button object and assign a variable to represent it
        Set ScrollBar = ActiveSheet.ScrollBars.Add(1, 1, 1, 1)

        '## use the btn variable to manipulate the button:
        With ScrollBar
            .Top = rng.Top
            .Left = rng.Left
            .Width = rng.Width
            .Height = rng.RowHeight
             .Min = 1
        .Max = 100
        .SmallChange = 1
    .LargeChange = 1
    .LinkedCell = "B" & i

        End With
    Next
End Sub
```